# select download place on user computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an asp.net website. It is an interface between user and sftp server. It means I have files in sftp server.I download the file, which user want ,directly into users computers without storing server which has website codes.

I need a small window that make user choose where to download the file which is stored in sftp server.

What should I do? Thanks..

Comment: Each browser shows a save as dialog doing the same thing that you want, why do you want to implement it yourself ?

Comment: Each browser shows it WHEN we give the direct path of file which is stored in the same server with the codes. But I couldn't able to give direct path of file which is in sftp like  sftp.example.com/examplefolder/exampleFile. It doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the "Save File" dialog, you can add a header to your response.

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=whatever.txt");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

You can leave the ContentType unset, or you can set it to a specific MIME type if you wish.

Comment: I need to get only PATH which user chose without downloading whatever.txt

Comment: You cannot do that through a browser. You could maybe build a Java applet or a Flash/Flex app to handle it though.

Comment: What are you looking for? Just go hunt through the Java API or the Flex API. If you're not familiar with either technology, you're going to have to go learn it, and a link from me is not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add special header to response to force browser to show save-file-dialog, e.g.:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
```

Comment: I need to get only PATH which user chose without downloading file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/images/sailbig.jpg") );
Response.End();
```

This will prompt an Open / Save As dialog box.

For more information : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET